# Java ArrayList standard "contains" method does not seem to work

Tags: arraylist, contains

I am working on a program in Java.
I have some seemingly very simple code related to a dialog where the user can add a color to a stamp's color property.

The problematic part is in the code executed when the user clicks on one of 2 buttons : either Cancel or Add. I simply want to check if the stamp already possess the color the user is trying to add by checking if the ArrayList of Colors associated with the stamp contains it by using the "contains" method of ArrayList. But the code to be executed when the color already exists never executes. When I add some debug code to print values it works but contains never works. Any idea?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if ( e.getSource() == btnAddColor )
        {//WE HAVE CLICKED btnAddColor
        if ( table.getSelectedRowCount() != 0 ) //THERE IS A CHOSEN COLOR IN THE JTABLE
            {
                String selectedColor=(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn())).toString();
                //FIRST WE HAVE TO CHECK THAT THE COLOR IS NOT ALREADY EXISTING FOR THIS STAMP
                if (Share.timbreNow.getColorList().contains( colorDao.findByName(selectedColor).get(0)))
                    {//WE DO NOT TAKE THE ADD ACTION INTO ACCOUNT BECAUSE IT IS AN ALREADY EXISTING COLOR
                        notificationPopup.setContent("The stamp already has this color !");
                        NotificationManager.showNotification(notificationPopup);
                    }

                else //WE CAN ADD THE COLOR
                    {
                        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() //Set a timer
                            {
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                                    {
                                        DialogAddColor.this.setVisible(false);
                                        DialogAddColor.this.dispose();
                                    }
                            });
                            timer.start();//Start the timer
                            notificationPopup.setContent("Adding the color \"" + selectedColor  + "\"");
                            NotificationManager.showNotification(notificationPopup);
                            Share.chosenColor = colorDao.findByName(selectedColor).get(0);  
                    }
            }

        else //NO CHOSEN COLOR
            {
                notificationPopup.setContent("No chosen color !");
                NotificationManager.showNotification(notificationPopup);
            }
    }

   else if ( e.getSource() == btnCancel )
    {//WE HAVE CLICKED btnCancel : LEAVE THE DIALOG WITHOUT DOING ANYTHING
        this.dispose();
    }
}//END OF METHOD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

verify that whatever kind of object you're using implements the `equals` method correctly.

Comment: My custom objects do not override the "equals" method. Shouldn't the "equals" method of the base class work if so?

Comment: the base implementation checks if they're the same object. if it's possible for you to have two equivalent objects, you need to implement that yourself.

Comment: please remember to upvote/accept if this resolves your problem.

Comment: I will. Just waiting for a second opinion before doing so.

Comment: Okay you mean that the base implementation only checks if the references are equal but do not check the contained fields. Am i correct?